# Программа не выводит значение

Tags: c#

Я написал простенькую игру, в которой угадываешь числа для двоих игроков. Но не могу понять, как выводить сообщение для другого игрока, ведь цикл не проверяет его значения. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это исполнить и что я делаю не так.

```
namespace hw2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game");

            Random rand = new Random();

            int bone1 = rand.Next(1, 101);
            int bone2 = rand.Next(1, 101);
            int count = 0;
            int player1;
            int player2;

            Console.Write("Enter name: ");
            string p1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter name: ");
            string p2 = Console.ReadLine();

            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.Write($"\n{p1} enter number: ");
                count++;
                player1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"\n{p2} enter number: ");
                count++;
                player2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (player1 < bone1 || player1 > bone1)
                {
                    if (player1 < bone1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n{p1} entered number is less than the guess. Try again!");
                }
                else if (player1 > bone1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n{p1} entered number is greater than the envisioned one. Try again!");
                }
            }
            else if (player2 < bone2 || player2 > bone2)
            {
                if (player2 < bone2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n{p2} entered number is less than the guess. Try again!");
                }
                else if (player2 > bone2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n{p2} entered number is greater than the envisioned one. try again!");
                }
            }

                else
                {
                    if (player1 == bone1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n{p1} congratulations, the number is right! Attempts: {count}.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (player2 == bone2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n{p2} congratulatipns, the number is right! Attempts: {count}.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите из Вашего кода все `else`.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду else if и else?

Comment: @RinSama Нет, я имею в виду только слово `else`.

Comment: А как мне тогда цикл закончить?

Comment: @RinSama Так же как и сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо это действительно заработало, но почему?

Comment: @RinSama Хм, ну попробуйте описать логику кода человеческим языком с `else` и без них. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Теперь Я понял, благодарю вас.